# How to move the "list of figures" (lot) in pandoc

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I want to place my "list of figures" (lot) to the end of the document, but pandoc puts the lot by default at the beginning, directly after the toc.

My .md looks like this:

```
---
toc: true
lof: true
---

# Heading 1
Lorem ipsum…

# References
:::{#refs}
:::
```

Note how it ist possible to move the Bibliography with a div to the end of my document.

With the LaTex snippet

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
```

the lof is moved, but only if converted as pdf.

Is there a solution to moving the lof to the end of a document, regardless of type (pdf, html...)?

Comment: A minimal working example will help you get a more precise answer. This post may help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322226/list-of-figures-at-the-end-of-contents

Comment: I believe you are conflating "List of Figures" (lof) and "List of Tables" (lot)?

Answer (score 3):

There is no format independent solution. The reason is that "list of figures" is only supported in LaTeX and ConTeXt output. So there is no way to move it in HTML and other formats, simply because it cannot be created in the first place.

For the formats that do support the creation of a lof, one can write a custom template: running `pandoc -D latex` will output the default template used with LaTeX. Save the output to a new file, search and move the `$if(lof)$` statement as desired, then use the new template with `--template my-template.latex`.